# Latest data on frequency of insurance claims

Tags: data-request

I have developed a new model which caters for frequency data with large number of zeroes and ones. I am looking for new and latest data on number of insurance claims for any types of claims. In insurance claims, many policyholders do not claim because it will affect their No-Claim Discount/Bonus provided by their insurance company. And usually, if they claim, they will claim only once because most policyholders are believed to be a good driver with enough experiences to not cause accident and takes good care of their vehicles. Is there any datasets that gives information like the following:

1. Policy Number or ID Number or any distinct information for the policyholders.
2. Number of times claimes in a particular time (a year or 10 years).
3. Type of Cars (based on the brand or cubic capacity or both).
4. Types of insurance coverage (if available).
5. Location (states or urban-suburban-city types).
6. Other informations.

The model will then be further developed to accomodate all these variables as covariates in my research. If anyone can direct me to pages/links regarding this, it will be highly appreciated.
p/s: It is okay if the data has been studied previously because it will allow us to do some comparison as well.

Comment: Googling `free insurance data` (no quotes) yields many data sets-- have you looked at these?

Comment: usually they are from reports and I did search insurance claim data but not free insurance data. Will try now.